# Multiple strings replacement from dictionary

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm going to create script which will take the key and value from the dictionary and use it for replacement in set of files.
I need replace "foo" to "foo1" if "target_value" found in the file. There are many different foo's. So, I guess dictionary will be suitable for that.

I started from the simple things:

```
    with fileinput.FileInput(filelist, inplace=True) as file:
        for line in file:
            if line.find('target_value'):
                print(line.replace("foo", "foo1"), end='')
```

For some reason this script just ignore line.find and replace everything with last line of code.
Could you help?

Comment: What does `target_value` do over here?

Comment: I rely on that when replace "foo" to "foo1"

Comment: Why not just use `in` instead of `str.find`?

Comment: `line.find()` returns the index of the substring, or `-1` if it's not found. `-1` is truthy, so you're doing the replacement even if the target value isn't found. The only falsey integer is `0`, so you do the replacement whenever the line doesn't start with `target_value`.

Comment: Also, do you want to test if `target_value` is anywhere in the file, or just each line?

Comment: There's no dictionary in your code.

Comment: thanks for clarification but how to create simple condition? if - then? change the line if other line exists. I'm looking target_value in the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Python's find command returns -1 if the value is not found, so you need something like:

```
with fileinput.FileInput(filelist, inplace=True) as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.find('target_value') > -1:
            line = line.replace("foo", "foo1")
        print(line, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with `str.find` is that it returns the index at which `"target_value"` occurs in `line`, so any integer from 0 to `len(line)-len(target_value)-1`. That is, unless, `"target_value"` doesn't exist in `line`; then `str.find` returns `-1` but the value of `bool(-1)` is `True`. In fact, the only time `line.find('target_value')` is `False` is when `"target_value"` is the first part of `line`.

There are a couple options:

```py
with fileinput.FileInput(filelist, inplace=True) as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.find('target_value') != -1:
            print(line.replace("foo", "foo1"), end='')
```

Or:

```py
with fileinput.FileInput(filelist, inplace=True) as file:
    for line in file:
        if 'target_value' in line:
            print(line.replace("foo", "foo1"), end='')
```

The second option is more readable and tends to perform better when `line` is long and `"target_value"` doesn't occur in the beginning of `line`.

```
>>> timeit('"target_value" in s', setup='s = "".join("foobar baz" for _ in range(100))+"target_value"+ "".join("foobar baz" for _ in range(100))')
0.20444475099975534

>>> timeit('s.find("target_value") != -1', setup='s = "".join("foobar baz" for _ in range(100))+"target_value"+ "".join("foobar baz" for _ in range(100))')
0.30517548999978317
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.find()`, you can use `if 'target_value' in line:` which is more expressive and does not involve return value conventions.

If you have multiple target keywords (and multiple replacements per target), you could build your dictionary in like this

```
replacements = { 'target_value1': [('foo','foo1'), ('bar','bar1')],
                 'target_value2': [('oof','oof'), ('rab','rab2')],
                 'target_value3': [('foobar','foosy'),('barfoo','barry')]}
```

Then find which target value(s) are present and perform the corresponding replacements:

```
with open(fileName,'r') as f:
     content = f.read()
     for target,maps in replacements.items(): # go through target keywords
         if target not in content: continue   # check target (whole file)
         for fromString,toString in maps:     # perform replacements for target
             content = content.replace(fromString,toString)

# you probably want to save the new content at this point
with open(fileName,'w') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

*Note that, in this example, I assumed that the target keyword flags the whole file (not each line).  If the target keyword is specific to each line, you will need to break down the content into lines and place the logic inside a loop on lines to perform the replacements on a line by line basis*

You don't actually need the replacement data to be a dictionary (this second example with line level single target replacements):

```
replacements = [ ['target_value1',('foo','foo1'), ('bar','bar1')],
                 ['target_value2',('oof','oof'), ('rab','rab2')],
                 ['target_value3',('foobar','foosy'),('barfoo','barry')]]

with open(fileName,'r') as f:
     lines = f.read().split("\n")
     for i,line in enumerate(lines):          # for each line
         for target,*maps in replacements:    # go through target keywords
             if target not in line: continue  # check target (line level)
             for fromString,toString in maps: # perform replacements on line
                 lines[i] = lines[i].replace(fromString,toString)
             break # only process one keyword per line

# to save changes
with open(fileName,'w') as f:
    f.write("\n".join(lines))
```